# Finding all integers satisfying an equation?

Tags: number-theory

My task is to find all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ which satisfy
$$
2x^2+2xy+y^2=25\quad\quad\text{(1)}
$$
**Is there a general approach of solving a task like this? If not, have you got tips for me, that might help me solving this?** Below are my attempts of solving this task:

First I tried to solve it as a differential equation:
$$
2x^2+2xy+y^2=25 \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad\frac{d}{dx}(2x^2+2xy+y^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(25) \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad4x+2y+2x\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad\frac{dy}{dx}(2x+2y)=-4x-2y \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-4x-2x}{2x+2y} \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+x}{x+y}
$$
Here I got stuck, so I tried to solve equation (1) like a quadratic equation (for $x$ as well as for $y$) and came up with this pair of equations (which didn't help either):
$$
x=-\frac{1}{2}y\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{4}y^2+\frac{25}{2}} \\
y=-x\pm\sqrt{(5+x)(5-x)}
$$

Comment: Your approach via differential equation is flawed at its heart. When you write $2x^2+2xy+y^2=25$, you mean that you have two integers $x$ and $y$ for which the equation is true. In order to justify deriving both sides, the equation would have to be true for all real $x$.

Comment: Hint: Because they are integers, then the expression inside the radical: $(5+x)(5-x)$ must be a perfect square.

Comment: [Binary quadratic forms](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/124/lectures/lecture23/lecture23/) and reduction theory may be of interest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These equations are called Diophantine equations and we don't know yet how to solve them effectively, we know only how to solve some particular cases, Your equation is equivalent to $(x+y)^2+x^2=5^2$ and we know that the only representations of $5^2$ as sum of squares are :$5^2=5^2+0^2=3^2+4^2$ (search for Pythagorean triples).

so you have either:

- $x+y=0$ $x=\mp 5$
- $x+y=\mp 5$ $x=0$
- $x+y=\mp 4,x=\mp 3$
- $x+y=\mp 3,x=\mp 4$

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for integer solutions. So differentiating the equation doesn't make any sense. Note that multiplying by $2$, we can rewrite
$$2x^2+2xy+y^2 = 25$$
as
$$4x^2 + 4xy + 2y^2 = 50 \implies (2x+y)^2 + y^2 = 50$$
Since we are looking for integer solutions, this means $y$ has to be odd and $y^2 \leq 50 \implies y \in \{\pm1, \pm3, \pm5, \pm7\}$.

- $y=\pm1 \implies (2x+y)^2 = 49 \implies 2x+y = \pm7$
- $y=\pm3 \implies (2x+y)^2 = 41 \implies $no solution
- $y=\pm5 \implies (2x+y)^2 = 25 \implies 2x+y = \pm5$
- $y=\pm7 \implies (2x+y)^2 = 1 \implies 2x+y = \pm1$

Solve each of the above cases to obtain $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You could point out that the reason $y$ must be odd is that otherwise both the squares would be multiples of $4$ and $50$ is not.